# What is the difference between [:,:,::-1] and [:,:,:]

Tags: python, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I write program to show images.

I try to understand what is the difference between the code:

```
plt.imshow(cv2.imread(file_paths[0])[:,:,::-1])
```

and

```
plt.imshow(cv2.imread(file_paths[0])[:,:,:])
```

Why does the first image is yellow and the second image is blue?

Answer (score 1):

In `opencv`, color channels are ordered as BGR, while `matplotlib` consider the image as RGB. So to show an image loaded by `cv2.imread` in `matplotlib` in a right way, the channels' order must be reversed. It can be done as:

```
plt.imshow(cv2.imread(file_paths[0])[:,:,::-1])
```

or

```
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(file_paths[0], 1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Comment: Using the latter form greatly increases the probability that you'll understand your code when you pick it up again in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **extended slices** in Python.
You can see the related Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[::-1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```